# Bind ODBC table to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, odbc

I have built a WPF form with DataGrid and would like to fill it with Table from ODBC database. My current code seems to be able to open connection but I am not able to populate data to DataGrid. Can somebody explain me why?

- TableName = COMPANY
- DatabaseName = DBFS

This part works (with commented out section in the end). WPF form appearing without errors:

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Windows;
using System.Data;

namespace DB_inspector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=0875;dbq=@DBFS;Uid=Master;Pwd=Password;");
            string strSql = "select * from COMPANY";
            dbConnection.Open();
            OdbcDataAdapter dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            dadapter.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(strSql, dbConnection);
            DataTable table = new DataTable("COMPANY");
            //dadapter.Fill(table);
            //this.DataGrid1.DataContext = table;
            //DataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
            //dadapter.Update(table);
            dbConnection.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

This does not work, it is running without errors but I can't see even WPF form appearing after some time waiting:

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Windows;
using System.Data;

namespace DB_inspector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=0875;dbq=@DBFS;Uid=Master;Pwd=Password;");
            string strSql = "select * from COMPANY";
            dbConnection.Open();
            OdbcDataAdapter dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            dadapter.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(strSql, dbConnection);
            DataTable table = new DataTable("COMPANY");
            dadapter.Fill(table);
            this.DataGrid1.DataContext = table;
            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
            dadapter.Update(table);
            dbConnection.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="DB_inspector.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DB_inspector"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DB_inspector.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Liinos_inspector"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DB database inspector" Height="595.404" Width="1005.571">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="478" Margin="10,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="978"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Margin="829,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Source="logo_small.jpg"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="10,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="489"/>
        <Button Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="516,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" Background="#FF73DA63" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What does the XAML look like? How many records are you exepcting?

Comment: There are quite a lot of records. About 900 rows with about 20 columns

Comment: If you get an error from a constructor ( which that is ) then the window will not be constructed and you wouldn't see a window. Add a try-catch with an exception in the catch method.  Put a break point in and step through. See what happens.

Comment: Not the XAML I was expecting. Can you show the actual XAML where this DataGrid1 resides. I used another ODBC driver and I get result without any issues.

Comment: Code seems to work. There are 900+ customers in database, it just takes too long time to populate data to DataGrid.